# Rename all files to .txt

Tags: powershell, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I am trying to rename all file to .txt. I have tried selecting all and renaming it only changes the name and not the extension.

```
Get-childitem
Rename-Item c:\temp\*.* *.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\*.* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + ".txt" } -WhatIf
```

`-WhatIf` is for confirming if the rename is correct or not. Remove that to do the real renaming

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\*.* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $_.Extension,'.txt' }
```

Comment: this will replace all instances of extension, for example `a.bin.file.bin` will become `a.txt.file.txt`